# Font Awesome aparece como "blocos" no nginx sob FreeBSD 10.1

Tags: nginx, unix, font

Tenho um site que transportei do CentOS para o FreeBSD usando rsync + mysqldump.
No CentOS + Apache funcionava normal no FreeBSD + nginx deu esse erro:
[image: erro]

Acredito que seja relacionado a este código que "converte" o \f086 em um ícone.

```
#primary_nav #nav_app_forums a:before {
    content: "\f086";
}
```

Ao invés dos ícones aparecem "blocos", estou usando o IP.Board 3.4.6 com o tema Dispersion e o ProMenu.

Alguem tem idéia de como resolver?

Obrigado.

Comment: Tem certeza de que o CSS do Font Awesome está sendo importado para a página?

Comment: Sim, sem erros no console do Chrome e chequei os paths.

Comment: Pra fazer um ícone do Font Awesome aparecer, é necessário que você coloque as classes em uma tag *i*, dessa forma: `<i class="fa fa-bed"></i>`. Sendo *fa-bed* a classe do ícone desejado. Veja se isso resolve seu problema. Caso não queira usar o `i`, vai ter que copiar todas as propriedades  da classe `fa` e da classe do ícone pra sua regra CSS.

Comment: Na verdade eu não editei nenhum código, é tudo do IP.Board e ProMenu: https://www.invisionpower.com/apps/board/ http://community.invisionpower.com/files/file/5435-promenu-basic/ o estranho é que funcionava normal no CentOS.

Comment: Aparentemente está faltando a fonte do **Font Awesome**. Verifique se os arquivos de fonte foram migrados corretamente, se não corromperam e tudo o mais. Teste também alterando o CSS para usar de outro lugar, tipo isto: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Pode inspecionar o elemento utilizando as ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador e ver a fonte que está realmente sendo utilizada nesses quadrados?

Comment: Aparece algum erro no console ao abrir a página?

Comment: Nenhum erro aparecia no console não. Essa pergunta é um pouco antiga, infelizmente não tenho o site mais...

Comment: Votei para fechar essa pergunta como não reproduzível. O texto da pergunta não tem informação suficiente para se saber qual é a causa do problema ou reproduzi-lo, vez que há inúmeras causas possíveis. O autor da pergunta (@sistematico) já não tem mais o site porque a pergunta é antiga. Desta forma, tentativas de produzir uma resposta (tal como a minha ou as duas respostas deletadas) serão tentativas de adivinhação que não tem como serem averiguadas. Logo, não há como se dar uma resposta correta a essa pergunta, apenas chutes, e por isso estou votando pelo fechamento.

Answer (score 1):

Às vezes eu tenho esse problema com o uBlock Origin, que acaba bloqueando o download de fontes do Font Awesome.

Caso seja esta a causa, a solução é simplesmente desbloquear a fonte no uBlock Origin ou outro tipo de adblock que você esteja usando. É verdade que você não tem como forçar o seu usuário a desbloquear, e portanto orientá-lo em casos como esse acaba sendo a melhor saída.