# Icones não aparecem - Font Awesome

Tags: css, font-awesome

Os ícones utilizados do font awesome não aparecem em meu site, fica só uns quadradinhos, não entendo porque.

É igual desse tópico: [LINK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58708/font-awesome-aparece-como-blocos-no-nginx-sob-freebsd-10-1)

Como não foi solucionado, postei novamente para pedir ajuda. Alguém saberia dizer o motivo disso?

---

No meu head está com um link do CDN:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-
awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
```

Estou usando na TAG `<i>`

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Unico CSS diferente que tenho em meu site é o CSS do meu reset:

```
/*RESET CSS*/
*, *:after, *:before{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.2;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1{font-size: 2em;font-weight: 300;}
h2{font-size: 1.8em;font-weight: 600;}
h3{font-size: 1.5em;font-weight: 800;}
hr{border-color: rgba(237, 234, 234, 0.18);}
p{margin-bottom: 15px;}
b,strong{font-weight: bold;}
mark{padding: 5px 10px; background: #eee;}
ul{list-style: none;}
img{border: none;max-width: 100%;vertical-align: middle;}
small{font-size: 0.75em;color:#555;}
a{text-decoration: none;color: #09f;}
a img{border:0;}
i{color:#FFF;}
```

Comment: Editei, @vnbrs!

Comment: @vnbrs o unico CSS que tem é meu reset, que coloquei agora na edição.

Comment: Lembrando, estou testando em localhost

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Qual seletor css tem prioridade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143850/3635)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na sua folha de estilos está utilizando o seletor universal, `*`, e sobrescrevendo a `font-family` para Open Sans. O problema é que o Font Awesome é uma fonte.

Você pode optar por retirar a linha `font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;` do CSS ou mudar seu seletor, como por exemplo:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Acredito que o `font-weight` e o `font-size` também podem te trazer problemas. Caso venha a acontecer, é só fazer o mesmo que exemplifiquei acima.

Comment: Nossa cara, que pamonhice a minha, nem percebi, obrigado mesmo!